# Robert Kraft - what is the reason for the prosecution's offered deal?

Tags: court, settlement

After [reading this article](https://sports.yahoo.com/robert-kraft-could-avoid-courtroom-humiliation-but-nfl-could-drop-hammer-on-patriots-owner-193304100.html) about Robert Kraft (football team owner allegedly caught having sex with a prostitute in a spa), it appears that the prosecution offered Robert Kraft a decent deal:

He has to "*admit that he **would have been** found guilty had the case gone to trial*",
and in exchange his only punishment (aside from the NFL's own internal discipline), would be:

- take an education course on prostitution
- complete 100 hours of community service
- subject himself to an STD screening test
- pay some court costs.

Presumably he's already familiar enough with prostitution, so doesn't need to be educated on it, but my real two questions are:

**Why would prosecutors in-general want someone to admit they "would have been" found guilty**, "if the case had gone to trial"? Why not just offer the deal in exchange for a guilty plea? How does it benefit the government for an admittance someone would've lost a trial?

**Why does the government demand someone subject themselves to an STD screening?** That just seems like an attempt to publicly humiliate that person. If the government legitimately is worried about the spread of STDs, and thinks someone likely has one, why don't they just say so, and advise that person to get a test? Isn't this an unnecessary intrusion into someone's personal medical decisions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about personal motivation of political office-holders, not the law or legal process.

Comment: *Presumably he's already familiar enough with prostitution, so doesn't need to be educated on it* I never have been to one of those courses, but I guess that their contents differ from the practicalities of being a customer.

Comment: To the first question, I don't think the government specifically *wanted* to let him make a [no contest plea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nolo_contendere) - they might rather have had him make a regular guilty plea - but that it's what they settled on after negotiation.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yeah, that was a poor joke on my part. =)  I presume they talk about things like the horrors of human trafficking, and the spread of STDs.

Comment: @Nij Yea, I wasn't sure where to ask it - where here, or the Politics stack exchange. I should've worded it better - I'm not looking for the specifics of this case, but why, in general, would the government be interested in such things?

Comment: @Nij I tried to word it better; does that help, or is it still to broad?

Comment: You're still asking "why does [X] want [Y]?" - there's no rewording such a question to be about the law rather than politics.

Comment: @Nij True! I think I'm asking more a question about government, not about law, which is indeed offtopic. I think I was just distracted that, "I know my question is not really about politics, and it involves prosecutors, so it must be about law...". I agree it should be closed as offtopic.

Comment: For the last point about demanding an STD test, is this case is famous in the USA then publicity could be a factor, but perhaps not so much for shaming but for spreading the "prostitution = STD" message. But this is just a guess as good as any other.

Comment: @SJuan76 That's a good point. Yea, it's semi-famous in the USA. It's been making the rounds for the past week with plenty of coverage, with late night hosts making all sorts of quips about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the politics.stackexchange.com site